# How can I access mouse events in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

Is there any way I can access the mouse events in Outlook 2007? I know you can access the mouse events for a custom form region. However I would like to access the mouse events of an inspector.
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide an specific example of what you try to achieve? Do you mean that you want to know whether a user has clicked onto a specific element or where the mouse position is?

Answer (score 0):

There are no Mouse events on th inspector but they may be another event that would help you ? What are you trying trap from a user point of view?